# Running BFS to find shortest path from bottom to top of a graph

Tags: c++, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve a task, with restraints: \$1 \le B,L,S \le 100 000\$. And for this I use a BFS from every edge at the bottom of the graph, and run a BFS till we reach `y=0`. However, when running the code in the compiler, I get a timeout error. Why do I get a TLE error and what do I change in this code to pass?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

int bfs(const vector< vector<int> > &g, pair<int, int> p)
{
queue <pair<pair<int, int>, int> > que;
vector< vector<bool> > vis(100000,vector<bool>(100000,false)); //visited
int x, y, k = 0; //k = distance
pair <pair<int, int>, int> next, start;
pair <int, int> pos;
start = make_pair(make_pair(p.first, p.second), 0);
que.push(start);
while(!que.empty())
{
    next = que.front();
    pos = next.first;
    x = pos.first;
    y = pos.second;
    k = next.second;
    que.pop();

    if (y == 0) {
        return k;
    }
    if((g[x+1][y] == 1) && (vis[x+1][y] == false))
    {
        que.push(make_pair(make_pair(x+1, y), k+1));
        vis[x+1][y] = true;
    }
    if((g[x][y+1] == 1) && (vis[x][y+1] == false))
    {
        que.push(make_pair(make_pair(x, y+1), k+1));
        vis[x][y+1] = true;
    }
    if((g[x-1][y] == 1) && (vis[x-1][y] == false))
    {
        que.push(make_pair(make_pair(x-1, y), k+1));
        vis[x-1][y] = true;
    }
    if((g[x][y-1] == 1) && (vis[x][y-1] == false))
    {
        que.push(make_pair(make_pair(x, y-1), k+1));
        vis[x][y-1] = true;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
int B,L,S,x,y, shortestDist = 1234567;
cin >> B >> L >> S;
vector< pair <int, int> > p; //stones in the first row
vector< vector<int> > g(B, vector<int>(L,0));
for(int i = 0; i < S; i++)
{
        cin >> y >> x;
        g[y][x] = 1; // stone = 1, empty = 0
        if(y == B-1)
            p.push_back(make_pair(x, y));    
}

for(int i=0;i<p.size();++i)
     {
        shortestDist = min(shortestDist,bfs(g,p[i]));
     }
cout << shortestDist + 2 << "\n"; //add 2 because we need to jump from shore  to river at start, and stone to river at end
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you give a link to the problem source? Is it publicly available?

Comment: It was from a site where you can practice in programming, but the original problem statement was only in Slovakian hence it had to be translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your approach resulting in a complexity of O(B*(B*L+S)).

The first problem is, that you run bfs B times in the worst case if the whole first row is full of stones. You have S stones and every stone has at most 4 neighbours, thus every call of bfs would run in O(S), but you do it B times, thus your algorithm will need for some cases about O(B*S) operations - I'm sure the author of the problem took care that programs with this running time will time out (after all that are at least 10^10 operations).

A possible solution for this problem is to start bfs with all stones of the first row already in the queue. Having multiple starting points can also be reached by adding a new vertex to the graph and connecting it to the stones in the first row. The second approach is not that easy for your implementation, because of the data structures you are using.

And this (data structure) is your second problem: you have S=10^5 elements/vertices/stones but use B* L=10^10 memory units for it. It is around 2G memory! I don't know what are the memory limits for this problem - it is just to much!  Initializing it B times costs you B* B*L operations in overall.

A better way is to use a sparse data structure like an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). But beware of filling out this data structure in O(S^2) - use a set for O(SlogS) or even unordered_set for O(S) running times.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand now what I did wrong with my code. Thank you for the help! :)